# Implementing search in GoogleMaps Android API, with zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I am trying to implement searching GoogleMaps in Android app, and found solution in:

```
geoCoder.getFromLocationName("New York", 5);
```

which returns a `List<Address>`.

The problem I have is that Address object contains information about longitude and latitude, which is great, but not zoom level info one gets when searching Google Maps. For example: if the search is for a country, Google maps sets zoom level to show the whole country, unlike searching for an address with street number which will display much higher zoom level.  JS has it. How about Android?

How can I get zoom information when searching GoogleMap API (v1) in Android?  Tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Google Maps geocode API.

Example request: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New%20York&sensor=false

Comment: I came across that, and was considering it. So nothing native to Android?

Comment: There might be a library that wraps geocode / places / directions APIs. Maybe [Google Search API](http://google.com/) can help with that ;)